# Unbound textbox compared to value in table, Datatype mismatch?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am currently working on a project for a class where I am building a database in MS Access and using a bit of SQL and VB for the first time. I am attempting to include a login feature to this project.

My form uses this code on a button labelled "login" to take in input from the user in unbound textboxes, named txtEmployeeID and txtPassword, and compare them values in table Employee_T, named EmployeeID and EmployeePW. EmployeeID is an integer value while EmployeePW is a string.

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.txtEmployeeID) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter EmployeeID", vbInformation, "EmployeeID Required"
        Me.txtEmployeeID.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Else

        If (IsNull(DLookup("EmployeeID", "Employee_T", "EmployeeID = ' & Me.txtEmployeeID.Value & ' "))) Or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("EmployeePW", "Employee_T", "EmployeePW = ' & Me.txtPassword.Value & ' "))) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect LoginID or Password"
        Else
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

However, after pressing the login button I am met with an error: Run-time error '3464': Datatype mismatch in criteria expression. 
Could someone point me in the right direction? I feel as though my error is in the way I am referencing my variables.

I have never looked at any visual basic before this project and I do not have a book/teacher/classmate to refer to as visual basic is not something we are specifically learning.

Thank you very much in advance for any insight, and apologies for any formatting errors. This is my first post.

Comment: It looks like you're concatenating vaues in your DLookup incorrectly. `'" & password & "'` for strings and `" & employeeID & "` for integers.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was my problem, most likely due to lack of understanding. Won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're concatenating vaues in your DLookup incorrectly.

`'" & password & "'` for strings

`" & employeeID & "` for integers

When compiled, these are going to look like :

```
string - '" & variable & "' -> Compiled -> 'YourVariableValue'
integer - " & employeeID & " -> Compiled -> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes like this: (be careful for using it exactly like I post it here)

```
If (IsNull(DLookup("EmployeeID", "Employee_T","EmployeeID = """ & Me.txtEmployeeID.Value & """"))) Or _
(IsNull(DLookup("EmployeePW", "Employee_T", "EmployeePW = """ & Me.txtPassword.Value & """"))) Then
```